# MongoDB + PHP Item wont remove()?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, database

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but with MongoDB and PHP i'm trying to do this:

```
$db->textures->remove(array("_id"=>$_GET['texture_id']),array("safe" => true))
```

But nothing happens. I did a `print_r` and it says:

```
Array ( [err] => [n] => 0 [ok] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap, looks like since im removing a MongoID i have to do this:

```
$db->textures->remove(array("_id"=>new MongoId($_GET['texture_id'])),array("safe" => true));
```

Comment: AFAIK only if the ID was added as a MongoID.

Comment: Isn't _id always automatically added as a mongoid?

Comment: Yeah, if an _id is not supplied when it is created, then yes. A MongoId maps to an ObjectID which is an object, which is why just supplying the ID didn't work. But, you can supply your own (non-MongoID) _id values if you want, and search on them without using the MongoId object.

Comment: eg, have a look at the following:
    > db.test.save({ name: "Test Object 1"});
    > db.test.save({ _id: "abc123", "name" : "Test Object 2" });
    > db.test.find();
    { "_id" : ObjectId("4cca41c9d86d000000006d33"), "name" : "Test Object 1" }
    { "_id" : "abc123", "name" : "Test Object 2" }

Answer (score 2):

The following Oscar Godson's answer is correct but now deprecated since 1.5.0 :

```
$db->textures->remove(array("_id"=>new MongoId($_GET['texture_id'])),array("safe" => true));
```

should now be written using the *"w"* option like that :

```
$db->textures->remove(array("_id"=>new MongoId($_GET['texture_id'])),array("w" => 1));
```

[Sources](http://php.net/manual/fr/mongocollection.remove.php)

Answer (score 1):

To remove a document based on its ID, you need to ensure that you pass the ID as a MongoID object rather than just a string:

```
<?php 
$id = '4b3f272c8ead0eb19d000000';
// will not work:
$collection->remove(array('_id' => $id), true);

// will work:
$collection->remove(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If an ID is not supplied when the record is saved then yes, you'll need to use the MongoID object to build the correct search criteria. You can, however, define the _id to be whatever you want - a plain integer, text, timestamp, etc - that you can use to search on as with any other property.

See the following CLI output as an example - the first object has an _id that contains an ObjectId type, but the second contains a simple string. A search by the string works as normal:

```
> db.test.save({ name: "Test Object 1"});
> db.test.save({ _id: "abc123", "name" : "Test Object 2" });
> db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4cca41c9d86d000000006d33"), "name" : "Test Object 1" }
{ "_id" : "abc123", "name" : "Test Object 2">
db.test.find({"_id" : "abc123"});
{ "_id" : "abc123", "name" : "Test Object 2" } }
```

Comment: Just curious, but is there a way to have Mongo auto generate and ID as it does by default but make it a string? I like that the ids are long and near impossible to guess and that they are done by default. If not i can generate them myself, just curious if there was a way to just change the type on insert.

Comment: AFAIK, not that I know of, I'm no mongo guru though.